# Why is only one div being appended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to append several div elements dynamically. However, only one div element is being created/displayed in the browser when I go to test the code. I tried looking for similar questions/issues like this, but found nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.divcreate {
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
    border:2px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i=0; i < 12; i++) {
        $("body").append("<div></div>").addClass('divcreate');
    }
});
```

Comment: `$("<div></div>").addClass('divcreate').appendTo(document.body)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `addClass` function applies to your `body` selector, your code is adding 12 divs, but then applying the `divcreate` class to your body element. Below is a simple working version that sets the class inline.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    for (var i=0; i < 12; i++) {
      $("<div></div>").addClass('divcreate').appendTo(document.body)
    }
});
```

```css
.divcreate {

height:75px;
width:75px;
border:2px solid #000000;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't realize that I was applying the class to the body.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the class to the body.  If you put text in the div you will see that the div is in fact being added 12 times.  See this jsfiddle `->` https://jsfiddle.net/ehj6wzew/

Answer (score 0):

Add class first and then append

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    for (var i=0; i < 12; i++) {
      $("body").after($('<div></div>').addClass('divcreate'));
    }

});
```

```css
.divcreate {

height:75px;
width:75px;
border:2px solid #000000;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```